# Force an Attachment to be open before Submitting a Form

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using a BPM software to create an approval process.

The first user will submit information related to a document and attach a document to the form being submitted for approval.

I am trying to build an approval form that requires the user to open an attachment (normally a PDF) before being able to submit the approval decision.  Once the user opens the attachment (or clicks a link) the approval selections would be enabled (Approve, Rework, Cancel) and the user could submit.

I would be happy if the selections are enabled and the submit is disabled, but either way the submittal cannot happen until AFTER the file or link is clicked.

Comment: Well, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking only about client validation, this would do the trick:

```
$('#pdfLink').click(function(){
    $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

your submit button html should look like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" disabled />
```

Comment: Client-side validation is all I need.  In the end, we are only seeking to ensure the user clicked the link (presumably to open a file and view it) before actually approving the request.

Comment: Let me now if you had trouble implementing the answer.